# Extjs 6 grid + JSON

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, grid, extjs6

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "aaa": {
        "list": {
            "count":"1",
            "data": [
                {"id":"1","username":"user1","email":"user1@test.com"}
            ]
        }
     }
}
```

And this is my Store:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields : [ 'id', 
               'username', 
               'email'],
    autoLoad : true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'server/users'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            successProperty: 'success',
            root: 'data',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        }
    }
});
```

And this is my Grid:

```
xtype: 'grid',
title: 'Users',
id: 'users', 
store: store,
columns: {
  items: [
    {text: 'ID', dataIndex: 'id', editor: 'textfield'},
    {text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', editor: 'textfield' },
    {text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', editor: 'textfield' },
]
},
```

But this code is not working. I don't show JSON data on my grid. I think the problem is that I don't reach JSON elements.
How can I reach this elements? (aaa.data.id, aaa.data.name, aaa.data.email is not working)

Comment: if the path is always static you can specify `'root':'aaa.list.data'` in the `reader` `config`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want (or can't) change the structure of your JSON, change the reader of the proxy on your store to correspondent with the data structure of your JSON.

```
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    rootProperty: 'aaa.list.data',
    totalProperty: 'aaa.list.count'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `root` should be `root: 'aaa.list.data'`. The `root` is supposed to point to the array of records. `data` doesn't appear in the top level object returned at all. It would be like saying:

```
var o = {
    aaa: {
        data: [{}]
    }
}
console.log(o.data); // Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [reader's transform method](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-transform) to format the data before the store processing takes place.